# Java cardLayout wrong parent

Tags: java

I know this question has been asked before but i cant seem to make the answers work, nor understand them.

What i am trying to do is to swap panels which button click.
This is the my main function:

```
public class CreateWindow extends JFrame{

    public CreateWindow() {
        this.setTitle("Test GUI");

        this.putIcon();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(512, 512);

        this.add(new CreatePanel());

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

and this is where i try to create the panels:

```
public class CreatePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    JTextArea directoryText;
    JFileChooser chooser;
    String directory;
    ArrayList<File> files;
    CardLayout cards;
    JPanel panel1, panel2;

    public CreatePanel() {
        this.setSize(256, 256);
        cards = new CardLayout();
        this.setLayout(cards);

        files = new ArrayList<>();
        panel1 = new JPanel(null);
        panel2 = new JPanel(null);

        this.add(panel1, "panel1");
        this.add(panel2, "panel2");
        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
    panel2.setBackground(Color.blue);

        cards.show(panel1, "panel1");

    }
}
```

And i keep on getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout
    at java.awt.CardLayout.checkLayout(CardLayout.java:404)
    at java.awt.CardLayout.show(CardLayout.java:526)
    at jeasussaves.CreatePanel.<init>(CreatePanel.java:54)
    at jeasussaves.CreateWindow.<init>(CreateWindow.java:29)
    at jeasussaves.JeasusSaves$1.run(JeasusSaves.java:22)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: You need to do `cards.show(this, "panel1");`. The first parameter for `show` requests for the parent of the component you wanna switch to

Comment: oh god, such a stupid question... thank you very much. If you want make a proper answer so i can give you the points

Answer (score 4):

`CardLayout#show(Container, String)` requires you to specify the "deck" you want to use as the first parameter, then a "card" from that deck as the second parameter.

In this case, your `JPanel` (the one being extended) is the deck (since it's the one using `CardLayout`) and `panel1` is a card, since you added it to the deck. Change your `cards.show(panel1, "panel1")` to `cards.show(this, "panel1")`.

There's no need to display your first card after adding all the cards. The first card you add is the first card to be displayed